# Как дать время для слайдшоу

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всё подключил и так далее, каждый 7 секунд картинка меняется, что прописать чтобы хотя бы каждый 3 секунды менялось,   `$(function(){` а дальше что? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
$(function(){

  SyntaxHighlighter.all();

});

$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery FlexSlider v2.2.2

Среди параметров есть:

```
slideshowSpeed: 7000, //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
animationSpeed: 600, //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы о setTimeout()? Я правильно Вас понял?

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/
```

Comment: да, только не пойму, какую из них скопировать, я редактировал, посмотрите, куда именно вставить

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял